# Проблема с подключением VPN pptp

Tags: centos, администрирование, vpn

На сервере(centos 6.7) год назад я поднял vpn через pptp. Когда рубался свет, ну или ещё что-то происходило, у меня всегда были команды которыми я впн поднимал.

> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp —dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
>
> service iptables save
>
> service iptables restart

Сейчас одному из отделов нужно переодически заходить в сеть другой фирмы по впн, они(другая фирма) настроили у себя впн, но я не мог туда попасть! Но после того как я подгрузил модули, все заработало, и от нас по впн можно подключиться к ним(другой фирме)! вот эти строчки

> modprobe nf_nat_pptp
>
> modprobe ppp-compress-18
>
> modprobe ppp_mppe

Но в чем соль, тогда невозможно подключиться к нам из внешки по впн. Т.е. получается либо работает так, что от нас можно подключиться к ним(другой фирме), ЛИБО, наоборот, из внешки (откуда угодна пробовал, из дома, от друзей) можно подключиться к нам по впн. ПОЧЕМУ так?